# How to write Junit test for the controller with Httpservletresponse as argument?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit5

This is my Controller With httpservletresponse as a argument. how to write junit test case for it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/excelexport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getExport(@RequestHeader(required = true) 
           String userid, HttpServletResponse response) {
        service.exportExcel(response);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `MockHttpServletResponse` is for in the Spring Test module.

Comment: When I use MockHttpServletResponse i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException @M.Deinum

Comment: Then your setup isn't correct.